# Keep multiplying found values in an array error with recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I struggle with this coding "challenge".
I need to look for the **original** value in **nums**. If its there, multiply by two
and redo the whole thing.
Return the value if there is no more same value.

It works on a lot of test cases but I get a weird error with this set while debugging.
After I iterate the array and was ready to return the right value, instead of returning the 16, it calls the **findFinalValue** again and iterates itself from 16 down again to 4.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution s = new Solution();
        int[] nums = {8,19,4,2,15,3};
        System.out.println(s.findFinalValue(nums, 2));

    }

}
```

```
class Solution {
    public int findFinalValue(int[] nums, int original) {
        
        for(int n: nums){
            if(n == original){
                original*=2;
                findFinalValue(nums, original);
            }
            
        }
        return original;
    }
}
```

Comment: "If its there, multiply by two" - multiply _what_ by two? The value in the array, or the argument passed into the method?

Comment: "Return the value if there is no more same value" - return which value? The original value, or the value after you multiplied it by two?

Comment: You're right, I could've worded that better. Here is the original description because I don't know if you can share the link on stackoverflow:
1. If original is found in nums, multiply it by two (i.e., set original = 2 * original).
2. Otherwise, stop the process.
3. Repeat this process with the new number as long as you keep finding the number.
Return the final value of original

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that your problem is that your have not implemented recursion properly:

```
class Solution {
    public int findFinalValue(int[] nums, int original) {
        int found = original;
        for(int n: nums){
            if(n == original){
                found = findFinalValue(nums, found * 2);
            }
            
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not iterating from 16 to 4, it is how recursion works. You need to pass the result back or store it in a global variable. Once the dead-end is achieved in recursion it backtracks and comes back to its original state.

Solution

```
class Solution {
    public int findFinalValue(int[] nums, int original) {
        int isPresent = false;
        for(int n: nums){
            if(n == original){
                isPresent = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPresent) {
           original = findFinalValue(nums, original*2);
        }
        return original;
    }
}
```

Frankly speaking, you can optimize it by sorting the array at first and then using binary search for finding elements, in addition, the array passed in the next state can be reduced till the index has read. Because original has become twice

Comment: Okay I get your Solution but I still don't get why mine is wrong. I've just started learning.
My thought was: When the original isn't found in the array anymore it would skip the if and just return the value in original. Instead of returning and jumping out of the function, it just straight up jumps back in. I thought return would end the function no matter what and return the value.

Comment: You are thinking right but one thing missing is it will return to the caller, not to directly first call. So when original is not found in any it will return back to the place it was called and so on....

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use recursion, but since I think you're asking about a recursive solution, I would do it like this:

```
public int findFinalValue(int[] nums, int original) {
    return IntStream.of(nums).anyMatch(n -> n == original)
           ? findFinalValue(nums, 2 * original)
           : original;
}
```